# boost::filesystem::path::native() returns std::basic_string<wchar_t> instead of std::basic_string<char>

Tags: c++, boost

Although the following code compiles on Linux, I'm no being able to compile it on Windows:

```
boost::filesystem::path defaultSaveFilePath( base_directory );
defaultSaveFilePath = defaultSaveFilePath / "defaultfile.name";
const std::string s = defaultSaveFilePath.native();
return save(s);
```

where base_directory is an attribute of a class and its type is std::string, and function save simply takes a const std::string & as argument. The compiler complains about the third line of code:

*error: conversion from 'const string_type {aka const std::basic_string}' to non-scalar type 'const string {aka const std::basic_string}' requested"*

For this software, I'm using both Boost 1.54 (for some common libraries) and Qt 4.8.4 (for the UI that uses this common library) and I compiled everything with MingW GCC 4.6.2.

It seems that my Windows Boost build returns std::basic_string for some reason. If my assesment is correct, I ask you: **how do I make Boost return instances of std::string? BTW, is it possible?**

If I made a bad evaluation of the problem, I ask you to please provide some insight on how to solve it.

Cheers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows, boost::filesystem represents native paths as `wchar_t` by design - see the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#path-Encoding-conversions). That makes perfect sense, since paths on Windows can contain non-ASCII Unicode characters. You can't change that behaviour.

Note that `std::string` is just `std::basic_string<char>`, and that all native Windows file functions can accept wide character path names (just call FooW() rather than Foo()).

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. Can you suggest a way to make this code more portable? Should I declare my strings that refer to filesystem paths as boost::filesystem::path::string_type throughout my code? What's the good practice here?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with the paths. The most portable, but most restrictive, thing is to stick to `filesystem::path` and use the file manipulation and iostream functionality provided by boost. If you need something more specific you lose the portability but gain flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

> **how do I make Boost return instances of std::string? BTW, is it possible?**

How about [`string()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#string) and [`wstring()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#wstring) functions?

```
const std::string s = defaultSaveFilePath.string();
```

there is also

```
const std::wstring s = defaultSaveFilePath.wstring();
```

Comment: This solves the compilation problem, but I guess my main concern now is to know if there are and what are the good practices to write a portable code for both Linux and Windows using Boost Filesystem path objects.

Answer (score 4):

Boost Path has a straightforward function set to give you a std::string in "native" (i.e. portable) format. Use `make_preferred` in combination with `string`. This is portable between the different operating systems supported by Boost, and also allows you to work in `std::string`.

It looks like this:

```
std::string str = (boost::filesystem::path("C:/Tools") / "svn" / "svn.exe").make_preferred().string();
```

Or, modifying the code from the original question:

```
boost::filesystem::path defaultSaveFilePath( base_directory );
defaultSaveFilePath = defaultSaveFilePath / "defaultfile.name";
auto p = defaultSaveFilePath.make_preferred(); // convert the path to "preferred" ("native") format.
const std::string s = p.string(); // return the path as an "std::string"
return save(s);
```